# Disable changing of width in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table, fixed-width

I'm trying to create a "fixed-width" table, but it somehow changes the column width whenever the data in column is bigger than rest of them.

For example, following table changes the width on the last number, which is 10.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td colspan="2">9</td> 
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 2 algorithms for tables in CSS, triggered by the property `table-layout`:

- `table-layout:`**`fixed`** will adapt cell widths to what the author (you) want, as far as possible
- `table-layout:auto` (default value) will adapt cell widths to their content.

CSS

```
  table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tk4J8/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `column-width` to specify width of table columns - it's a [suggested optimal guideline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width) for browsers that isn't really meant for fixed width layouts. Use `colgroups` instead.

Remove the `column-width` style in your stylesheet, and add this to your `table` tag before any `tr` or `td` tags:

```
<colgroup>
    <col span="1"></col>
    <col span="1"></col>
    <col span="1"></col>
    <col span="1"></col>
</colgroup>
```

And add this to your stylesheet:

```
colgroup col {
    width: 100px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phirephoenix/GK5d6/).

Here's the [Mozilla documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup).